# FFMPEG audio streaming to icecast lets media players stop after each song

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, icecast

I have set up FFMPEG audio streaming to an icecast2 server.
It works, but when I use a loop to stream different songs, media players stop after each song. In detail:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -hide_banner -re -i test$i.mp3 \
  -c:a libvorbis -ac 1 -b:a 96K -content_type audio/webm -f webm \
  icecast://source:password@localhost:8000/stream
done
```

Media players (vlc, mpv, mplayer) would stop after each of the 3 test files. I have to press play again and again. For icecast2 I use the default settings (queue-size 524288, burst-size 65535).

How can I have a continuous flow so players don't have to be restarted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually generate a continuous stream.

One may might be to use a named pipe and have your main FFmpeg encoder to Icecast read raw PCM from the pipe.  Then, your `for` loop could have other FFmpeg instances decoding the audio files and writing PCM to the pipe.

Comment: One more thing: when I stream via "-f flv rtmp://server/live" it works fine. Why does RTMP work, but not icecast?

Comment: Probably depends on what your server and clients are doing.